# What is the difference between lua 5.0.2 modules and 5.3.5?

Tags: c++, dll, lua

i try to write some c++ code for lua. First i used the latest version 5.3.5 and i was able to register some new functions. But the final program that i want to write the code for uses 5.0.2. After i compiled the old source and build the dll with lua 5.0.2, `require` cannot read the file

```lua
Lua 5.0.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2004 Tecgraf, PUC-Rio
> require("remaster_IO.dll")
stdin:1: error loading package `remaster_IO.dll' (remaster_IO.dll:1: `=' expected near `É')
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function `require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

This is the dll code:

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

    __declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_remaster_IO(lua_State* L);

}

#define lua_register(L,n,f) \
        (lua_pushstring(L, n), \
        lua_pushcfunction(L, f), \
        lua_settable(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX))

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int rema_add1(lua_State* L) {
    double d = luaL_checknumber(L, 1); // get item 1
    lua_pushnumber(L, d + 1);
    return 1; // number of items returned
}

int luaopen_remaster_IO(lua_State* L) {
    Beep(200, 200);
    std::cout << "Hello World!!!" << std::endl;

    lua_register(L, "average", rema_add1);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think `require()` only understands files of actual lua code, and a different method is used for shared libraries.

Comment: I have never used Lua 5.0, so I may be wrong, but try `loadlib([[C:\path\to\remaster_IO.dll]], "luaopen_remaster_IO")()` instead of `require("remaster_IO")`

Comment: loadlib worked fine for the interpreter, but i'm afraid the game that i need this for has a reduced version of lua 5.0.2. Any chance to do it with require or dofile?

Answer (score 0):

If you look [at the documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#5.1) (scroll down to `require`, back then it didn't have per-function anchors yet…), you'll see that `require` in 5.0 indeed only loads Lua files.  If you don't have access to `loadlib`, you're probably out of luck.

(There's even a good chance that they compiled Lua in such a way that dynamic linking of libraries is not supported *at all* – so even if you were aware of a bug that you could use to find, push & (re-)add `loadlib`'s pointer as a Lua function value, that might not be enough…)